# Most efficient way to check for messages in array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I'm currently working on a chess-like game in c++ and was wondering if there were any pattern or good programming ways to check for messages between classes.

In my problem I have two classes, a boardSquare- and a GameBoard-class (BoardSquareManager). The boardsquare has functionality that when you click a square a boolean value will be set to true meaning the boardSquare has been clicked. Currently in the GameBoard-class I have an array of BoardSquares and in order to check if one boardsquare has been clicked I go through every BoardSquare each tick and see if anyone has been clicked, it looks like this.

```
void AGameBoard::CheckMessages()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
 {
    if (BoardSquareArray[i]->GetWasClicked())
    {

        iClickedTile = BoardSquareArray[i]->GetSquareNum();

        BoardSquareArray[i]->DeactivateClick();

        bTileWasClicked = true;
    }
 }
}
```

In my opinion it feels unnecessary to have to look through the entire array all the time just so I can get information if a tile has been clicked or not, do you know any better way of doing this on?

I appreciate all answers!

Comment: You must be using some framework for the GUI. What is it? You could then notify your manager using techniques, which that framework offers.

Comment: Add a stack or vector in which you push clicked square coordinates. Pop them while postprocessing, and when it's empty you're done.

Comment: @LogicStuff I am currently building it in Unreal Engine 4.

Comment: @Jongware That's actually a really smart solution, thanks I'll try that!

Comment: You're welcome :) As I am not that intimate with STL, if this is enough for you get get it to work, feel free to add your own solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now I have gone with making a static class which has a queue. I use this class to send messages from the BoardSquare to the Gameboard. (Making a static class might not be the "best" solution in long term goals but since this is a prototype I was figuring it might work out for now)

Code for Static MessageClass:

```
/*
* Public variables
*/

static void SendMsgToBoard(int& tile) { TileNumbers.push_back(tile); }

static int& RecieveMsgFromSquare() { return TileNumbers.front(); }

static void SquareMsgRecieved() { TileNumbers.pop_front(); }

static bool IsEmpty() { return TileNumbers.empty(); }


private:

/*
* Private Variables
*/

static std::deque<int> TileNumbers;
```

New Code for Boardsquare:

```
    messagePasser::SendMsgToBoard(iSquareNum);
```

New Code for Gameboard:

```
if (!MessagePasser::IsEmpty())
{
    if (IsTileOccupied)
    {
        //Do stuff...
    }
    else
        //Do Other Stuff...

    MessagePasser::SquareMsgRecieved();
}
```

Comment: What is the point of making a static class? I have this quite often, but I never get the point. From a design point of view, Looks like a singleton. it is a very strong coupling between two entities. It makes testing the classes individually harder, and will introduce nice problems because of the static initialization order problems in C++. If you go with a queue, make it a normal class and let the two Board-classes share access to a normal object.

Comment: I would rather not make a static class because of the reasons you've pointed out, but I'm not either sure how to implement it with a normal class and then share the object.  I could pass the object onward with pass by reference but then it just seems easier to make it static class which I can then introduce to the different source files for the classes.

Comment: If the two classes share a queue, the straight-forward way would be to to use an aggregation and give the classes two non-owning indirect members, e.g. pointers, shared_ptr or something else. The only thing you gain from the static solution is easy access without going through the member, but you hide the dependency and introduce other problems. I would rather avoid it. Also, what happens if you need a the same mechanism between two other classes? Then you have to duplicate the static class which is even worse. I think "static class" is just another name for the singleton anti-pattern.

Comment: You're right I'm going to look into it and see if I can make some better solution than the static class, thanks for the advice! :)

Answer (score 2):

Have considered the Observer pattern? The classic Design Patterns book from E. Gamma contains a lot patterns which come from implementing GUI applications. Other patterns which are probably interesting are Command (do want to undo moves?), Decorator, Chain of Command, Composite, Strategy, Template Method. I would definitely recommend to read the book.

Comment: I have read a similar book which is called "Game Programming patterns" Which does also explains alot of patterns such has Observer and the like, although I deemed most of these patterns too complicated for just communication between two classes. Altough I might look into some other patterns as well, thanks for the advice!

In the end I went with a simple queue which I pushed the clicked tiles on!  :)

Comment: @Tim0n I forgot to mention the Model-View-Whatever family of patterns. It is more a pattern to structure your application, but it is often a good solution for interactive applications.

Answer (score 0):

Make some std::vector or std::stack and push there click events with coordinates of tile which was clicked. You can also make some onClick method which takes pointer do AGameBoard and sent to it message about clicked tile.

Search something on the internet about events handling.

Comment: Yea I made a static class with a queue on which I pushed the clicked tile on, It seems to work for now, if it needs to be more complicated I will take a look at making some sort of clickMethod.